# Writing a Dequeue Function in Racket

Tags: racket

I trying to do a queue exercise and I am meant to write enqueue, dequeue, top and size functions for the given queue. The dequeue function is currently giving me trouble. The desired result for the dequeue function is shown below.

```
(define q (make-queue))
(enqueue q 10)
(enqueue q 20)
(enqueue q 30)
(dequeue q)
10
(dequeue q)
20
(dequeue q)
```

My code currently looks like this

```
(module queue racket
  (provide make-queue enqueue dequeue top size) ;queue-tests)
  (struct queue (front back size) #:mutable #:transparent)

    (define (make-queue) (queue null null 0))

(define (enqueue q elt)
    (set-queue-size! q (+ (queue-size q) 1))
    (set-queue-back! q (cons elt (queue-back q)))
    )

(define (dequeue q)
    (cond  ((eq? (queue-size q) 0) null)
           ((null? (queue-front q))
           (begin
           (set-queue-front! q (cdr (reverse (queue-back q))))
           (set-queue-back! q null)
           (set-queue-size! q (- (queue-size q) 1))))
           (#t 
           (begin
           (set-queue-front! q (cdr (queue-front q)))
           (set-queue-size! q (- (queue-size q) 1))))))

  (define (top q)
    (cond ((eq? (queue-size q) 0) null)
          ((null? (queue-front q)) (last (queue-back q)))
          (#t (car (queue-front q)))))

  (define (size q)
    (queue-size q))
```

Please what is wrong with the dequeue function? I am fairly new to Racket and explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is that wrong? What do you want it to produce instead? Also, where's the definition of `top`?

Answer (score 1):

Your question suggests that you're somewhat at sea; in particular, you don't give the sense that you understand the pieces that make up your program. I think I would steer you toward writing test cases *inside* the module that test the enqueue and dequeue function.

Apologies if I've misunderstood your situation!

Comment: Honestly I am new with coding in Racket but I believe I can handle the test cases. Just focus on the dequeue method itself and the desired output. Try giving some explanation if you know what is wrong with the code

Comment: You're missing the point.  As far as I can tell, the code doing exactly what it's supposed to.  Echoing John's answer: you simply haven't told us what dequeue's behavior is.  What is it supposed to return?  The point in forcing you to express the test cases is precisely so you are forced to say what you get back from the function.  As far as I can tell, it doesn't return **anything**.  Is that what you want?  We're not telling you to write the test cases because it's busywork: we're telling you to do it because as soon as you do it, the error should be staring you in the face!  :)

Answer (score 1):

Do a much smaller test case.

```
(define q (make-queue))
(enqueue q "hi")
(dequeue q)
```

More than that, don't treat test cases as mere *printf* statements.  What you really want to do is write out what you know the queue state needs to be at particular points in time.  And you want to express those expectations in terms of real code with [check-equal?](http://docs.racket-lang.org/rackunit/api.html#%28def._%28%28lib._rackunit/main..rkt%29._check-equal~3f%29%29).  Write out what the queue should be after every step, then use *check-equal?* to catch exactly where your expectations and the code are diverging.

Otherwise, your test cases aren't actually "testing" anything besides the lack of a crash.  You want to get more out of your test cases: you want them to test **behavior**.

Here are two examples of test cases:

```
(require rackunit)
;; ..  after your definitions
(let ()
   (define q (make-queue))
   (check-equal? q (queue null null 0)))

(let ()
   (define q (make-queue))
   (enqueue q 42)
   (check-equal? q (queue null '(42) 0)))
```

Note, I've made a deliberate mistake with the second test case!  Note that it mistakenly expects the queue size to be zero.  So fix that.  :)

Do the same kind of testing for *dequeue* as well.

Other low level details:

I do not understand the third case.  I expected to see an *else* there, but I do not, so I have no idea what's going on there.

*cond* has an implicit *begin* built in already, so it's preferable to say:

```
 (cond [<test>
        <body-1>
        <...>
        <body-n>] ...)
```

instead of:

```
(cond [<test>
       (begin
         <body-1>
         <...>
         <body-n>)] ...)
```

Comment: I get where you are all going. I have found a way to revise the test cases but in the meantime could we please focus on the dequeue function itself and the desired output..Thanks